# Cobertura -java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class does not have a default interface

Tags: cobertura

I am using Cobertura to code coverage for Integration test. I am facing below issue while deploying instrumented jar in JBoss server.

```
DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:  Deployment "vfszip:/D:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/test/some_jar.jar/" is in error due to the following reason(s):
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Class class com.someclass does not have a default interface
```

Here are the steps I followed so far:

1. Downloaded cobertura-1.9.4.1.
2. Using this command obertura-instrument.bat C:\some_jar.jar I generated the .ser file and instrumented jar for some_jar.jar.
3. Placed the jar in JBoss server test/ folder.
4. Copied the .ser file to JBoss/bin folder.
5. Copied the Cobertura.jar to Jboss/lib folder.
6. Run the JBoss server.

Please let me know if I am missing any thing here.

Comment: No solution is there for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a configuration file error because you possibly have not adjusted a setting before starting for the first time.